# Observer pattern: delay action after event trigger

Tags: java, observer-pattern, watchservice

My code works properly. I just have a question from design perspective.

You can copy/paste both class and test class - they should work out of the box.

**Problem description:**

I have a class, which watches directory for new/modified/deleted files and fires event in case of any change. This is implemented using observer pattern.

```
interface IFileObserver
{
    void onFileChange(String filename, String action);
}

public class FileWatcher implements Runnable
{

private Path _directory;
private WatchService _watchService;
private List<IFileObserver> _fileObserverList;

public FileWatcher(Path directory)
{
    _directory = directory;
    try
    {
        _watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        _directory.register(_watchService, ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_MODIFY, ENTRY_DELETE);
        _fileObserverList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println("Unable to create FileWatcher object!");
    }
}

public void register(IFileObserver fileObserver)
{
    _fileObserverList.add(fileObserver);
}

private void updatesEvent(String filename, String action)
{
    for (IFileObserver observer : _fileObserverList)
    {
        observer.onFileChange(filename, action);
    }
}

private void startWatching()
{
    WatchKey key = null;
    boolean reset = true;
    while(reset)
    {
        try
        {
            key = _watchService.take();
            outerloop:
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents())
            {
                String filename = event.context().toString();
                WatchEvent.Kind<?> kind = event.kind();
                switch(kind.name())
                {
                    case "ENTRY_CREATE":
                        updatesEvent(filename, kind.name());
                        // Files on create will normally trigger ENTRY_CREATE and ENTRY_MODIFY
                        // break to outerloop will prevent catching ENTRY_MODIFY when create is expected
                        break outerloop;
                    case "ENTRY_MODIFY":
                    case "ENTRY_DELETE":
                        updatesEvent(filename, kind.name());
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Retrieving watch key interrupted!");
        }

        reset = key.reset();
    }
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    startWatching();
}
```

The problem is, that to use the data sent by the event I have to Thread.sleep before. As you can see in my tests below I use Thread.sleep(100) before each assert block - without that tests fail.

```
public class FileWatcherTest implements IFileObserver
{
private int _updatesCount = 0;
private String _filename;
private String _action;

@Test
public void FileWatcher() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    File directory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    assertTrue(directory.exists());
    assertSame(0, _updatesCount);

    Path path = Paths.get(directory.getPath());
    FileWatcher fileWatcher = new FileWatcher(path);
    fileWatcher.register(this);

    Thread thread = new Thread(fileWatcher);
    thread.start();

    String filename = "the-file-name.txt";
    File file = new File(filename);
    if (file.exists())
    {
        file.delete();
    }

    assertTrue(createFile(file));
    Thread.sleep(100);

    assertSame(1, _updatesCount);
    assertEquals(filename, _filename);
    assertEquals("ENTRY_CREATE", _action);

    assertTrue(modifyFile(file));
    Thread.sleep(100);

    assertSame(2, _updatesCount);
    assertEquals(filename, _filename);
    assertEquals("ENTRY_MODIFY", _action);

    Thread.sleep(250);
    assertTrue(deleteFile(file));
    Thread.sleep(100);

    assertSame(3, _updatesCount);
    assertEquals(filename, _filename);
    assertEquals("ENTRY_DELETE", _action);
}

private boolean deleteFile(File file)
{
    return file.delete();
}
private boolean modifyFile(File file) throws IOException
{
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file, true);
    writer.append("another line appended by ENTRY_MODIFY");
    writer.close();
    return true;
}
private boolean createFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file, "UTF-8");
    writer.println("The first line");
    writer.println("The second line");
    writer.close();
    return file.exists();
}

@Override
public void onFileChange(String filename, String action)
{
    _filename = filename;
    _action = action;
    _updatesCount++;
}
```

But I find this not nice, because if someone else uses this class they will not know you need to sleep and it will cause problems.

Can Thread.sleep(100) be forced in any way i.e. on each implementation of IFileObserver interface?

Answer (score 0):

What you said is right. When you get a create notification within 100 milliseconds in your system, it takes around 8400 in mine. So, a better test design would be that to wait for a logic state to change for a certain period instead of a mere `Thread.sleep`. Something like

```
private void waitUntilUpdateCountChangesFrom(int count) throws InterruptedException {
    int sleepTime = 10;
    int maxPolls = 10000/sleepTime;
    int i=0;
    for (; i<maxPolls; i++) {
        if (_updatesCount != count) {
            break;
        }
        Thread.sleep(sleepTime); // sleeps a little to give a turn to file watcher thread
    };
    System.out.println("waited " + (i*sleepTime) + " milliseconds");
}
```

Then call it like

```
    assertTrue(modifyFile(file));

    waitUntilUpdateCountChangesFrom(1);

    assertSame(2, _updatesCount);
    assertEquals(filename, _filename);
    assertEquals("ENTRY_MODIFY", _action);
```

One another thing I noticed is that, at times in my system, I get ENTRY_MODIFY too gets received first for file creation. So it may be a good idea to expect either of MODIFY or CREATE for file creation like below:-

```
    assertTrue(createFile(file));

    waitUntilUpdateCountChangesFrom(0);

    assertSame(1, _updatesCount);
    assertEquals(filename, _filename);
    List<String> createActions = Arrays.asList("ENTRY_CREATE", "ENTRY_MODIFY");
    assertTrue(createActions.contains(_action));
```

My processing flow was almost like given below:-

```
    Going to create .... 
    Received event: ENTRY_CREATE on file: the-file-name.txt
    waited 8440 milliseconds
    Going to modify .... 
    Received event: ENTRY_MODIFY on file: the-file-name.txt
    waited 8430 milliseconds
    Going to delete .... 
    Received event: ENTRY_DELETE on file: the-file-name.txt
    waited 8420 milliseconds
```

Comment: ENTRY_MODIFY for file creation is an expected behaviour. This is because when you create a file, under the hud it doesn't only get created, there is more steps to the process. So even if you add ENTRY_CREATE you will still get notifications regarding modify. To resolve this, I create a list of observed files and compare what is in the list and what is not.